# How to pass data into an angular.js UI bootstrap modal controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using **Angular.js UI bootstrap** modal, how can I pass data into a modal popup's controller? I am currently trying:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'partials/confirmation-modal.html',
    controller: 'confirmationModal',
    resolve: {
        foo: function() { return 'bar'; }
    },
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: true
});
```

The controller `confirmationModal` is:

```
    (function(_name) {
        /**
         * @ngInject
         */
        function _controller($scope, foo) {
            console.log(foo);  
        }

        angular
            .module('myApp')
            .controller(_name, _controller);
    })('confirmationModal');
```

But this errors with:

```
Unknown provider: fooProvider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to define the "confirmationModal" controller with `angular.module('app').controller(...)` instead.

If you want to use a string to refer to a controller, you need to register it to an angular module.

So, you have two ways to make it work:

1.Use string

In modal settings:

```
controller: "confirmationModal"
```

In controller definition (assume "app" is your module name):

```
angular.module('app').controller("confirmationModal", function($scope, foo) {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

2.Use function itself

In modal settings:

```
controller: confirmationModal
```

In controller definition:

```
var confirmationModal = function($scope, foo) {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

Can you tell the difference?

Comment: When I try: `controller: confirmationModal ` I am getting: `confirmationModal is not defined`.

Comment: Found my problem. I was setting the controller to use in both the modal options, and in the template itself with `ng-controller`. That was really hard to spot.